# rspec should_receive(x).with(parameter) goes missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This simple controller example

```
describe 'create' do

  it 'creates a panel' do
    panel = SimplePanel.make! 

    TestingGroup.any_instance.should_receive(:add_panel!).with(panel, [SampleType::SERUM])

    post :create, {
      submission_id: submission.to_param,
      testing_group_id: testing_group.to_param,
      sample_type_ids: [SampleType::SERUM],
      panel_ids: [panel.id]
    }
  end

end
```

produces the following result

```
Failure/Error: post :create, {
  #<TestingGroup:0x00000006685910> received :add_panel! with unexpected arguments
     expected: (, [1])
          got: (#<SimplePanel id: 266, name: "Some Simple Panel", description: nil, type: "SimplePanel", active: true, test_type_id: 1, species_id: 1, autonomous_panel: true, related_panel_id: nil, lock_version: 0, created_at: "2013-09-02 06:08:08", updated_at: "2013-09-02 06:08:08">, ["1"])
```

My problem is that the panel object (the first argument) appears to be completely nulled out of the expectation in the test result.

```
expected: (, [1])
```

It doesn't appear to be null, or an empty string, it's just gone.  Outputing the value of the panel object
immediately prior to setting the expectation reveals no surprises, it's an ActiveRecord object that's been
persisted to the database.

Changing the expectation to:

```
TestingGroup.any_instance.should_receive(:add_panel!).with(instance_of(SimplePanel), [SampleType::SERUM])
```

produces the following result

```
 Failure/Error: post :create, {
   #<TestingGroup:0x00000006ff82e0> received :add_panel! with unexpected arguments
     expected: (#<RSpec::Mocks::ArgumentMatchers::InstanceOf:0x00000006f4a208 @klass=SimplePanel(id: integer, name: string, description: text, type: string, active: boolean, test_type_id: integer, species_id: integer, autonomous_panel: boolean, related_panel_id: integer, lock_version: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)>, [1])
          got: (#<SimplePanel id: 268, name: "Some Simple Panel", description: nil, type: "SimplePanel", active: true, test_type_id: 1, species_id: 1, autonomous_panel: true, related_panel_id: nil, lock_version: 0, created_at: "2013-09-02 06:22:17", updated_at: "2013-09-02 06:22:17">, ["1"])
```

Which seems equally as bizzare.  Any ideas what's going on here?

EDIT: The following is typically what is created by SimplePanel.make!

```
attributes:
  id: 2
  name: Some Simple Panel
  description: 
  type: SimplePanel
  active: true
  test_type_id: 1
  species_id: 1
  autonomous_panel: true
  related_panel_id: 
  lock_version: 0
  created_at: 2013-09-02 07:33:19.032650000 Z
  updated_at: 2013-09-02 07:33:19.032650000 Z
```

Comment: Can you show sample value of `panel = SimplePanel.make! `?

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weird output is due to the description attribute in your SimplePanel model.  When RSpec generates the failure message for `should_receive(..).with(..)` it formats the arguments by using `args.collect {|arg| arg.respond_to?(:description) ? arg.description : arg.inspect}.join(", ")`. This causes the blank in `expected( ,[1])`, since the description on the mocked model is blank.

Edit: This issue has been fixed in current versions of rspec - https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/pull/417

Answer (score 1):

Your second argument is expected to be `[1]` (`Fixnum`), whereas the actual parameter is `["1"]` (`String`). Maybe the second parameter is what's failing your spec?

This doesn't explain the weird output in your first example though...

Comment: Weird output aside, this was the problem.  Once the assertion is changed to:
   `TestingGroup.any_instance.should_receive(:add_panel!).with(instance_of(SimplePanel), ["#{SampleType::SERUM}"])`

the test passes.

My assumption (after having a good night's sleep) is that it would never have passed with the original expectation
because the panel object that gets loaded by the controller action, although the same database record, is a different
ActiveRecord object and so it wouldn't have matched anyway.  The String vs Fixnum issue in the second argument
was then what was causing the test to fail.